# Jace:: Virtual machine Shutdown Error

Tags: java, c++, exception

What is wrong with this piece of code?

```
typedef ::jace::proxy::java::lang::String JString;
JString toString(const std::wstring& p)
{

    JString strVal(p.c_str());
    return strVal;
}
```

It throws exception `unhandled exception, jace::VirtualMachineShutdownError`, where I have passed p.c_str() to `JString` variable strVal.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you are getting that exception is wstring::c_str() returns `const wchar_t*` whereas `jace::String` class has no constructor that accepts a wchar_t*. The closest it comes to is `String( ::jace::JArray< ::jace::proxy::types::JChar > p0 );` which could be taken as an equivalent to `char*`.

A workaround to your problem could be something like this:

```
JString toString(const std::wstring& p)
{
    std::string s;
    s.assign( p.begin() , p.end() );
    JString strVal( s );
    return strVal;
}
```

This is not an efficient solution but works.

Comment: Somehow I can't comment on your post. Anyway, you should look in to other String proxy constructors especially one that takes a `Byte` array as input.